# Como resolver un error 'enumerate' is undefined

Tags: html, python, flask

Estoy intentando hacer un bucle de imagenes para mostrarla en un `slideshow` y me tome las imagenes de la carpeta sin necesidad de colocare el nombre de la imagen, pero me sale este error en el `nija2`:

> Ninja2: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'enumerate' is undefined

Python

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from glob import glob
import os.path
from os import path


app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
#   ruta_imagenes = []
 #       for root, dir, file in os.walk(app.static_folder.img):
  #      ruta_imagenes.append(file)

    imagenes = glob(os.path.join(app.static_folder, ".png"))
    render_template('index.html',imagenes=imagenes ) 





if __name__ == ('__main__'):
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

Html

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for _, ruta in enumerate(imagenes)  %}
    <div class="carousel-item ">
            {% if _ == 0 %}active{% endif %}
        <img src="{{ ruta }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: tu imagen no tiene nombre?? porque `glob(os.path.join(app.static_folder, ".png") ` es igual example `/static/.png` sin nombre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de un template jinja no puedes usar código python arbitrario. Jinja es un lenguaje aparte, aunque comparta algunas cosas con python.

En concreto, jinja no tiene `enumerate`. Pero a cambio tiene una variable llamada `loop.index0` que te devuelve en qué iteración del bucle estás, contando desde cero, por lo que puedes obtener el índice de bucle de esta forma sin necesidad de `enumerate()`.

Así que tu template podría quedar así:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for ruta in imagenes  %}
    <div class="carousel-item ">
            {% if loop.index0 == 0 %}active{% endif %}
        <img src="{{ ruta }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

O, para este uso concreto, queda más legible usar `loop.first` que te devuelve `True` si es la primera iteración del bucle. Por tanto:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for ruta in imagenes   %}
    <div class="carousel-item ">
            {% if loop.first %}active{% endif %}
        <img src="{{ ruta }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: gracias eso no lo sabia tendre que estudiar mas ninja, al probar de esta forma me lanzo este error: `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`

Comment: Pero eso ya no está relacionado con jinja. Parece que olvidaste el return delante del render_template

Comment: ha! asi ya me percate de que fue mi error xD, muchas gracias, ahora a ver como resuelvo para que aparescan las imagenes xD

Comment: No me había fijado en esa parte. No será `*.png` en vez de `.png` ?

Comment: Ya cambie todo está funcionando muchas gracias